# trying to extract samples from a .wav file

Tags: iphone, arrays, sample, wav

I'm attempting to obtain the samples from a .wav file & store them in an array (using objective c)

Does any know a good way to go about this?

So far it seems like libsndfile (http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) might be what I need to implement but I'm not sure where to start exactly (I'm relatively new to this)

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExtAudioFile` and `AudioFile` APIs in AudioToolbox.framework will do this for you. AQOfflineRenderTest may be a good sample to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the type of wave file...for example 16 bit mono sampled at 48 KHz, then the easiest way is to simply open the wave file as a binary file, move past the header, and start parsing the sample bytes.

A wave header looks like this if you are familiar with a C structure and if not there are plenty of online byte for byte references.

typedef struct
{
    char    chunkID[4];
    UINT32  chunkSize;          // only this field needs to be calculated
    char    format[4];
    char    subchunk1ID[4];
    UINT32  subchunk1Size;
    UINT16  audioFormat;
    UINT16  numChannels;
    UINT32  sampleRate;
    UINT32  byteRate;
    UINT16  blockAlign;
    UINT16  bitsPerSample;
    char    subchunk2ID[4];
    UINT32  subchunk2Size;      // and this field needs to be calculated
}WAVEHEADER;

Samples after this point are in order. If mono then there is one sample if stereo then one channel followed by the next channel at that time location.

Of course you can always simply parse the header if you don't already know the type of wave file and/or the size.